# How to optimize highly detailed jQuery animations for mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, optimization, mobile

I am working on a project, with no BoilerPlate, right now that uses a lot of jQuery animations such as paralax of several elements and the movement of 20 small .png images of clouds in the background (to make a cloud time-lapse) which run very slow and laggish on mobile devices. I want the same UX for both desktop and mobile environments. I am using mediaQueries to use smaller images/elements for smaller screens, but this doesn't seem to optimize mobile performance like I thought it would. I am familiar with HTML5-Boilerplate and BP-Mobile but am not sure if either one will help with my problem.

**How can I make these particular effects run smoothly on mobile?**

Comment: If the user doesn't have a high-end mobile phone (even if he/she does) html5 and intensive javascript won't run as smoothly on a pc. Your best bet is either cut down on animations or make it native app.

Comment: Use device detection and serve the website on a mobile domain for mobile platforms. There's a limit what a mobile phone can process - only high end mobile phones will be able to process all the effects smoothly. For exmaple my Nokia X6 almost dies on a simple slide effect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but those were the answers I was trying to avoid. Do none of the many new mobile frameworks out today assist in JavaScript animations?

Comment: You can try this library here http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/. Works great on mobile but you'll need to refactor your animations

Comment: GreenSock looks amazing! But I can't imagine how I will have to rewrite my jQuery paralax. Or rather replace it for GSAP code. Does GSAP work within jQuery script?

Comment: @user1644123 yes it works. I don't think it will be that hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to see if CSS3 animations have any effect. jQuery animate has severe performance drawbacks compared to CSS3. Even on a regular computer it is much smoother.

Comment: Yes, I am going to use CSS3 for the cloud timelapse but for Paralax effects I believe I must stick with jQuery, unless any of you know a better method.

Comment: I think stellar.js (http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) lets you use css3 transforms, look in the doc at "Configuring Scroll Positioning"